# Как добавить grpc в cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, библиотеки, сборка, grpc

Я установил grpc по инструкции из официальной документации, скомпилил .proto файл. Но при попытке добавить библиотеку в cmake произошла ошибка.

```
cmake файл
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(grpc_test1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(grpc_test1 main.cpp test_pd.cpp test_pd.h)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(grpc_test1 gRPC::grpc++)
```

Ошибка

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):   Found package
> configuration file:
>
> ```
> /home/anton/.local/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake
> ```
>
> but it set gRPC_FOUND to FALSE so package "gRPC" is considered to be
> NOT   FOUND.  Reason given by package:
>
> The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing:
> protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotoc

Как я понял, какой то флаг установлен в false и по этому cmake не может подтянуть библиотеку. Как это исправить? Как правильно добавить grpc в cmake ???

Comment: видимо вы не верно установили либу, лучше переустановите

Comment: Либа была установлена по инструкции, примеры скомпилились и работали корректно.

Comment: а почему вы в `find_package` используете опцию CONFIG?

Comment: без него тоже самое

Comment: я не спрашивал что без него, я спрашивал: зачем?

Comment: я взял этот пример из документации, не знаю что он делает